# regular expression in java inside an if block

Tags: java, regex

I can see the below regular expression in the code ...

```
if (amount.matches("[-+]?[0-9]*\\.?[0-9]+")) return true;
```

now my query is that what this regular expression represent that amount
should be numeric and what validation it will check

Comment: It is just checking if `amount` variable matches a signed decimal number.

Comment: @anubhava can you please share the example of i t also for example number would be -2345.76 like this

Comment: It matches any of these numbers: `-2345.76`, `-2345`, `+2345.76`, `+2345`, `2345`, `-.76`, `+.76`, `.76`

Answer (score 1):

Your regex works like this :

```
       "[-+]?[0-9]*\\.?[0-9]+"
[-+]? --> either a `+` or `-` or nothing. Followed by
[0-9]* --> any number of digits (* implies greedy check). Followed by  
`\\.?` --> 0 or 1 `.` (matched literally. ). Followed by 
[0-9]+ --> one or more digits
```

[demo here](http://regex101.com/r/mD7zL9/2)